# Close the stdin of boost::process child

Tags: c++, boost, stdin, boost-process

I'm trying to call a process with a string to its stdin, with Boost-1.64.0.
The current code is :

```
  bp::opstream inStream ;
  bp::ipstream outStream;
  bp::ipstream errStream;

  bp::child child(
    command, // the command line
    bp::shell,
    bp::std_out > outStream,
    bp::std_err > errStream,
    bp::std_in  < inStream);


  // read the outStream/errStream in threads

  child.wait();
```

The problem is that the child executable is waiting for its stdin EOF. Here child.wait() is hanging indefinitely…

I tried to used asio::buffer, std_in.close(),… But no luck.
The only hack I found was to delete() the inStream… And that's not really reliable.

How am I supposed to "notify" the child process and close its stdin with the new boost::process library ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean, _"delete() the inStream"_? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to used asio::buffer, `std_in.close()`

This works. Of course it only works if you pass it to a launch function (bp::child constructor, bp::system, etc).

If you need to pass data, and then close it, simply close the associated filedescriptor. I do something like this:

```
boost::asio::async_write(input, bp::buffer(_stdin_data), [&input](auto ec, auto bytes_written){
    if (ec) {
        logger.log(LOG_WARNING) << "Standard input rejected: " << ec.message() << " after " << bytes_written << " bytes written";
    }
    may_fail([&] { input.close(); });
});
```

Where `input` is

```
bp::async_pipe input(ios);
```

Also, check that the process is not actually stuck sending the output! If you fail to consume the output it would be buffering and waiting if the buffer is full.

Comment: You saved my week. I suppose may_fail is your custom handler for exceptions, so I call input.close() directly. And you have to call ios.run() too :)

Comment: Yup! Sorry for copying incomplete code this time :( http://paste.ubuntu.com/24701992/

Answer (score 2):

Closing the pipe by calling [`inStream.close();`](http://klemens-morgenstern.github.io/process/boost/process/basic_pipe.html#id314805-bb) when you're done writing to it. You can also close it while launching with [`bp::std_in.close()`](http://klemens-morgenstern.github.io/process/boost/process/std_in.html#namespaceboost_1_1process_1stdin_close).

The asio solution of course also works and avoids the danger of deadlocks.

Comment: Can you add to this answer? The OP used a boost::process::opstream object, which does not have a close() function. You link goes to documentation for a basic_pipe object, which does not seem to be a one-to-one replacement for boost::process::opstream.

Comment: You can access the underlying pipe by calling `opstream::pipe()`.